# Custom buttons in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm adding some custom buttons to my forms in MS Access, but somehow I can't make them work. In buttons properties Event tab I've changed 'On Click' event to call 'Event procedure'. Then in VBasic I'm selecting my button and from what I know this code should give me prompt, and if Yos is selected the form should close. But when I click my buttons simply nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong ?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdQuitApp_Click()
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to close the form?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbInformation, "Clasing the form.") = vbYes Then
DoCmd.Close
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the folder where the database resides as a Trusted Location.  See "[Create, remove, or change a trusted location for your files](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA100319991033.aspx)" for detailed instructions.